# Installing Windows 10 on a Mac Computer using the prepackaged Windows 10 USB

Tags: windows, macos, windows-10, mac, boot-camp

I wanted to install Windows 10 on my Mac and purchased the Windows 10 home edition physical copy which consists of a small usb drive with the OS on it and a registration card.

I have a Mac computer and would like to know if it is possible to install the Windows OS off that flash drive without making a custom flash drive that has the iso file on it as suggested by the Youtube videos I have been watching. It just seems to make sense that it should easier to do if you have an official Windows OS USB Stick with the OS preinstalled on it. i did a check on the usb stick and it did not have an .iso file on it so I'm leaning toward making my own custom usb, but I'm not sure yet.

Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the mode/year of your Mac? Generally, 2011 and older models use a DVD to install Windows. But, Apple does not officially support Windows 10 on these older models. The 2012 through 2014 models use a USB flash drive. The format of this flash drive is different from what a PC requires. The 2015 and newer models install directly from the iso file. So the these newer Macs do not need a flash drive or DVD.

Answer (score 0):

If your Mac can boot from the USB drive, go for it. If it can't, you could give creating it from an iso file a try.

But, as @DavidAnderson said in the comments, some older Macs do not boot from USB drives. Mine is from 2011 and *can* boot from USB drives. If yours cannot, installing [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html) or creating a bootable DVD will solve your problem.

Also, remember to create another USB drive using bootcamp for the drivers needed. If you don't, audio, wifi, Bluetooth, and other hardware might not work correctly.